# How to multiply binary image and rgb image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication, image-segmentation

I have a binary image which is the segmented form of another color image .

As you know , a binary image is 2-d but an rgb image is 3-d , how can i multiply them together ?

i tried this code which resulted in a strange pic

```
function  skinCrop(bwSkin,colorSkin)

for i = 1:size(colorSkin,1)
    for j = 1:size(colorSkin,1)
        if bwSkin(i,j) == 0
            colorSkin(i,j,:) = 0;
        end
    end
end
imshow(colorSkin);
end
```

The original image was [image]

The resulting image was :

[image]

I expected it to be a hand against a dark background , so why do the right part appear that way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong dimension length for your second dimension:

```
for j = 1:size(colorSkin,1)
```

should be

```
for j = 1:size(colorSkin,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid loops when not needed in matlab:

```
mask = cat(3,bwSkin,bwSkin,bwSkin);
output = mask.*colorSkin;
```

You might have to change the types in order for the multiplication to succeed:

```
output = uint8(mask).*colorSkin;
```

Or:

```
output = double(mask).*colorSkin;
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way to do the multiplication is

```
function mult = skinCrop( bwSkin, colorSkin )
% 
% multiplying 3D color image with 2D mask
%

mult = nsxfun( @times, bwSkin, colorSkin );

% show the result
imshow( mult ); title('skin cropped image');
```

As @zenopy noted, you might need to cast your variable to `double` type.